# JQuery Each function with ajax loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, alert, each

Hello guys this is my very first post in this forum.

I have this function

```
function TestePresenca(){
var msg = ''
$('#teste tbody tr').each(function(){
    var MemberId;
    var ClassId;
    var PresenceDate;
    var OClasse;

    var DataPre = $('#data_presenca').val();
    var TotBiblia = $('#tot_biblia').val();
    var TotOferta = $('#tot_ofertas').val();

    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        if($(this).index() == 0){
            MemberId = $(this).text();
        }

        if($(this).index() == 3){
            $(this).closest('tr').find("select").each(function(){
                ClassId = this.value;
            })
        }

        if($(this).index() == 4){
            OClasse = $(this).text();
        }           
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASE + '/save_list_presence',
        data: {pMemberId: MemberId, pClassId: ClassId, pOClasse: OClasse, pDataPre: DataPre, pTotBiblia: TotBiblia, pTotOferta: TotOferta},
        success: function(retorno){
            msg += retorno;
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Erro!');
        }
    });
});
alert(msg);}
```

My problem is the "alert(msg)" fires without a message, in debug time I see its fire then the each and ajax execute after and the "msg" variable are pupulated at the end, but the alert was fired before.

Anyone have any idea how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: classic misunderstanding of async :P

Comment: that is because, that's an asynchronous call

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. you can't fix it without making it synchronous(which is a terrible idea).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use this `async: false` in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASE + '/save_list_presence',
        async: false,
        ...
```

From the [**jQuery.ajax() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active.

Comment: This isn't really a solution.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks.
But if not the best solution can someone point the right way?

Comment: I have dicided to change the function I'll create a new function to make a json and will send this json to my php code then i'll make the loop in php and return my entire message to jQuery show it to me.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous - the code below it may run before the AJAX call finishes.